# Перенос элемента

Tags: html, css

Знаю вопрос конечно не из самых крутых ну все так

Как перенести параллелограмм в правую сторону

http://startiblitz.tk/2017/08/24/saaaaaaaa/

Comment: ваш код пожалуйста, вставьте скрин

Comment: какой параллелограм? как перенести? Добавь необходимый код непосредственно в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В своем коде замени

`<div style="text-align: right;">`

на

```
 <div align="right" id="figure">
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы `text-align: right` подействовал, добавьте вашему параллелограмму свойство `display: inline-block`.